# Unexpected token < when parsing XML in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, xml, xml-parsing

I've tried to use [`xml-js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js) and [`xml2js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-js) but both are returning the same error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

The xml example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

The code example:

```
var notes =require('./test.xml')

var convert = require('xml-js');
var xml =notes;

var result1 = convert.xml2json(xml, {compact: true, spaces: 4});
var result2 = convert.xml2json(xml, {compact: false, spaces: 4});

console.log(result1, '\n', result2);
```

Can you help with the solution to this? I've tried using `JSON.parse`, `JSON.stringify` but it is not working anyways.

I'm trying to parse an XML to convert to JSON, by the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue isn't with the XML parsing, it's with the fact you're using `require`, which loads Node.js module for reading another file. Instead, you should use a simple file reading method, such as `fs.readSync`:

```
fs = require('fs');
var notes = fs.readFileSync('./test.xml')
```

Comment: @spaceman: Recheck your work: `readFileSync()` would not yield the same error.

Comment: @spaceman please post the full code and the error you're getting. Your snippet has a mistake later on where you use `mNotes` instead of `notes`, but other than that, it works on my machine.

Comment: @Mureinik the error and the code is in the question, didn't change. Ive corrected this mistake you've noticed minute after posting it.

Comment: var fs = require('fs') || var xml = fs.readFileSync('./test.xml') ||  console.log(xml)

Comment: @spaceman that's a completely different error. You can't use `||` like that, just separate those three expressions to three different statements with semicolons (`;`s).

Comment: Just added the code and error using readfilesync to the question

Comment: @spaceman are you **sure** that's the code you're executing? it works fine on my machine (albeit it prints out a somewhat useless buffer)

Comment: @Mureinik hahaha, `||` was just to post in the comments area. Let's assume we all know the basics of programming

Comment: @spaceman: It's not about the `||`.  It's about you failing to extract a true [mcve].  Until you do that, we can't help you without guessing about the rest of your context, and that's extremely inefficient.

Comment: @kjhughes looooooooooooooooooooooool good saturday for you, mate. You misunderstood. My question was posted with a minimal, complete and verifiable example. If you are not coming to help, please don't mess with the question

Comment: @spaceman: The three lines of code alone you posted with `readFileSync()` simply do not yield the error you posted.  You're wasting everyone's time by not posting a ***complete*** MCVE.  Until you narrow the problem properly, you'll have a hard time figuring out your problem or getting help from others.  Moving on.  Good luck.